# Interface Builder XIB Compiler Error when adding constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I want to design a custom collection view cell using a xib. I have added a UIView over xib file and set constraints via storyboard for leading, trailing and Y position as centered vertically. All good if I try to build the project now.

When I want to add a constraint for the view's height to be half of the xib's height I get the following error message:

**Interface Builder XIB Compiler Error**
**Internal Error. Please file a bug at feedbackassistant.apple.com and attach "var/folders/32/.../"**

This constraint is added as an "Aspect ratio" and it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Any idea or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried changing that multiplier ratio for something with only integers? I think the aspectRatio only accepts integer numbers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You get the same by using 2:1 ratio, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have tried even with integers, the error still occurs.

Comment: *"add a constraint for the view's height to be half of the xib's height"* ... that's not clear. Show your xib layout to clarify which elements you are constraining.